# Failing to add item into array react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to access my array after querying my realtime database but an empty array is logged after extracting an item and adding it into my array. Do you know what may be causing this? Below is my code:

```
 const chatBox = async () => {

     let array_Message_ = [];
     try {
      setLoading(true);
      db.ref(`messages/`).once(`value`, snapshot => {
        if(snapshot.exists() == true) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                if(childSnapshot.key.includes(auth().currentUser.uid)){
                   var otherUserId = childSnapshot.key.replace(auth().currentUser.uid,"");
                   db.ref('messages').child(childSnapshot.key).orderByChild("sentWhileBlocked").equalTo(false).limitToLast(1).on('value',(dataSnapshots) => {
                   if (dataSnapshots.val()) {
                       for (let key in dataSnapshots.val()) {
                          db.ref(`users`).on(`value`, user_snapshot => {
                           user_snapshot.forEach(function(user_childSnapshot){
                              if(otherUserId == user_childSnapshot.key) {
                                    array_Message_.push({text:dataSnapshots.val()[key].text,timestamp:dataSnapshots.val()[key].timestamp, username: user_childSnapshot.val().username, messageKey:key, key:dataSnapshots.key})
                              }
                           })
                         });
                       }
                    }
                });
              }
           })
            console.log("array: "+JSON.stringify(array_Message_))
            setmessagesWithPhotos(array_Message_);
       }
    });
      } catch(err) {console.log(err);}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

console.log most probably will run before array_Message_.push, because db.ref(`users`).on and other such operations are async operations. So instead of writing semessageWithPhotos at the end write it in the last callback

```
 const chatBox = async () => {

 let array_Message_ = [];
 try {
  setLoading(true);
  db.ref(`messages/`).once(`value`, snapshot => {
    if(snapshot.exists() == true) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            if(childSnapshot.key.includes(auth().currentUser.uid)){
               var otherUserId = childSnapshot.key.replace(auth().currentUser.uid,"");
               db.ref('messages').child(childSnapshot.key).orderByChild("sentWhileBlocked").equalTo(false).limitToLast(1).on('value',(dataSnapshots) => {
               if (dataSnapshots.val()) {
                   for (let key in dataSnapshots.val()) {
                      db.ref(`users`).on(`value`, user_snapshot => {
                       user_snapshot.forEach(function(user_childSnapshot){
                          if(otherUserId == user_childSnapshot.key) {
                                array_Message_.push({text:dataSnapshots.val()[key].text,timestamp:dataSnapshots.val()[key].timestamp, username: user_childSnapshot.val().username, messageKey:key, key:dataSnapshots.key})
                          }
                       })
                       console.log("array: "+JSON.stringify(array_Message_))
                       setmessagesWithPhotos(array_Message_);
                     });
                   }
                }
            });
          }
       })
   }
});
  } catch(err) {console.log(err);}
```

}

like so.